# Regex doesn't work with PHP, but works in Ruby

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex that works in Ruby, but doesn't work in PHP:

```
$filename = 'files/Dial.txt';
$input_lines=fonl($filename,80);
echo $input_lines;
$pattern = "^\[(?<DateTime>[^]]+)\]\s+(?<TypeConnection>\b.*?(?:\W+\w+)}?\W+.*?\b)\s+'(?<User>.*?)'\s+(?<Detail>.*?$)";
//$pattern = preg_quote($pattern, '/');
preg_match_all("/".$pattern."/", $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);
```

and shows below error

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs\REGEX\index.php on line 11

What is wrong in this regular expression sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different regex delimiter and don't forget to enable multi-line modifier `(?m)` inorder to make your regex to work on multiple lines.

```
$filename = 'files/Dial.txt';
$input_lines=fonl($filename,80);
echo $input_lines;
$pattern = "(?m)^\[(?<DateTime>[^]]+)\]\s+(?<TypeConnection>\b.*?(?:\W+\w+)}?\W+.*?\b)\s+'(?<User>.*?)'\s+(?<Detail>.*?$)";
//$pattern = preg_quote($pattern, '/');
preg_match_all("~".$pattern."~", $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);
```

Comment: it's work correctly in http://www.phpliveregex.com/ but in my code not work some "/" add to start and end

Comment: it's supposed to be "/" as delimiters:
    preg_match("/".$pattern."/", $input_lines, $output_array);

Comment: addind "/" in $pattern dont help

Comment: return empty array with regex subjects

Comment: could you provide a sample input along with expected matches?

Comment: [29/Jul/2014 18:08:04] Kerio VPN client 'babak' disconnected from 188.159.36.88, connection time 00:05:09 like that

Comment: use multiline modifier. `(?m)`

Answer (score 0):

Check the example i hope it will be helpfull for u:-

```
preg_match("/(?<DateTime>[^]]+)\]\s+(?<TypeConnection>\b.*?(?:\W+\w+)}?\W+.*?\b)\s+'(?<User>.*?)'\s+   
(?<Detail>.*?$)", "2014-11-01 14:40:02", $results)
```